# Failing to connect remotely to sqlserver in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am facing a challenge to connect remotely to sqlserver in vb.net. I am using MSSql Server 2014 Express Edition, The Error Message is as follows:

> Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=184; handshake=14923;

My Vb.Net code is as follows:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=77.246.xx.xx,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=company_info;User ID=CSPOS;Password=password1;")

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     

        Try
            connection.Open()

            TextBox1.Text = "You have connected to sql server successfully!!"
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green
            connection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            TextBox1.Text = ex.Message
            TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

I am stuck, I do not know how to handle it and make things work.

Comment: Express edition is usually installed without the possibility of remote connection. Did you check the `sp_configure` to see how is the flag of the "remote access" ?

Comment: Yes I did so and the config_value=1, and the error is still there.

Comment: Have you set your instance of SQL to accepts mixed authentication (SQL logins and Windows logins) ?

Comment: Yes I did that, is there another version of sql server you can reccommend ?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/  doesn't quite look like you connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Update your connection string to

```
Data Source=77.246.xx.xx,1433;Database=company_info;User ID=CSPOS;Password=password1;Persist Security Info=True
```

It is works for me in VB.NET

Comment: I have tried   ```Data Source=77.246.xx.xx,1433;Database=company_info;User ID=CSPOS;Password=password1;Persist Security Info=True``` but the exception is still there. Is it possible to use the wireless network for the server?

Comment: Yes, wireless also working for me, I suggest you use SSMS (which is free) connect to the server with the same user id and password and see what is going on.

Comment: when connecting from my pc using this string ```Data Source=SERU-PC\myserver;Initial Catalog=company_info;User ID=CPOS;Password=password1;Integrated Security=False```, It works fine

Comment: Check your MS SQL server port, SQL authorization and firewall.

Comment: Thanks, I have restarted the server and the connection is now working perfectly using the connetion string you have just given above

Comment: I am glad you solved the problem. Please make it is correct answer when you have time which will help another people as well.